# Static files not loading on Heroku : Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I am deploying my Django application on Heroku. It has been deployed successfully. But static files are not loading.

I followed [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) link, but when Whitenoise 3.x is included, the command

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

fails.

my Procfile:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
web:python manage.py runserver
web: gunicorn MovieTracker.wsgi --log-file -
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

I have also tried with :

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

and also :

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0
```

The settings.py file is:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tracker',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/tracker/static")
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

with whitenoise enabled, ERROR:

[image: Build error]

Comment: Also, your Procfile is completely broken. The only thing it should contain is the second line, `web: gunicorn MovieTracker.wsgi --log-file -`.

Comment: That I have mentioned in the question, when I enable whitenoise, the collectstatic command fails. and the same link I have mentioned as "tried".

Comment: is debug set to true? django cannot serve static files if you set debug to false.

Comment: @ParijatPurohit that is irrelevant, OP wants to use WhiteNoise to serve the static files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Even tried with that single line.

Comment: Then you need to show the errors you got, not just that it "failed".

Comment: @ParijatPurohit Yes, I am aware of that, currently DEBUG is set to True.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok wait.

Comment: You're making it very hard to help you. Why have you posted that code as an image? And why haven't you enabled the STATICFILES_STORAGE setting, which is clearly wrong in that traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is version conflict between whitenoise and Django in the project.
The project uses Django 1.6 whereas whitenoise version that was being used was

> Whitenoise 3.x

Compatibility follows:

> Django 1.6 and lower with Whitenoise 2.x

Settings are given in [this](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/legacy-2.x/django.html) link for whitenoise 2.x.

> Django 1.7 and above with Whitenoise 3.x

Follow [this](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) for whitenoise 3.x.

Set the version in requirements.txt accordingly.

In the Procfile, just the following line is enough.

```
web: gunicorn MovieTracker.wsgi --log-file
```

Comment: Also note that support for Django 1.6 (including security fixes) ended in April 2015, so you should really upgrade your project to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the leading slash on your STATIC_ROOT sub-path.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "tracker/static")
```

Comment: You do need to show the actual error message from collectstatic.

Comment: There is no error in Build or in logs.
Build : Successful.
Logs: State changed from starting to Up.

Comment: collectstatic worked fine when I corrected the bug, as mentioned by you.
But still static files are not loaded.

Comment: What should the status of this?
    heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0 or 1 ?

Comment: And shall I include whitenoise in settings?

Comment: When whitenoise enabled. ERROR:
'ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module whitenoise.middleware: "cannot import name FileResponse"'

Comment: Please update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: Error importing module whitenoise.storage: "cannot import name ManifestStaticFilesStorage"

Comment: What does that error have to do with the previous one? Stop posting single lines in comments; post the *whole error message and traceback* as an update to the question. Also state which version of Django you are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155425/discussion-between-omkar-deshpande-and-daniel-roseman).